# Coordinate descent for constrained least squares

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I have a least squares problem of the form
\begin{align}\min_{\vec{a}}&\quad\|\vec{y} - X\vec{a}\|^2 \\\text{s.t.}&\quad\|\vec{a}_{I}\|^2 \leq 1,\\&\quad I \in A\end{align} where $\vec{a}_{I}$ denotes a subvector of $\vec{a}$ with indices $I$, $A$ a set of sets, and all $I$ are non overlapping.

I know that coordinate descent does usually not work on constraint least squares problems, such as with linear constraints. However, I was wondering if this also holds for these kind of quadratic constraints? Can we solve such problems with coordinate descent followed by a projection if necessary or will we run into some situation where we get stuck?